# How to install libusb?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I want to install libusb in ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have downloaded libusb-1.0.9.tar.bz2 file from official site "http://libusb.org" but now I am unable to install it. I want to use libusb for Reliance usb for net connection.

As I am new to linux so please mention every command that I need to run in terminal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: :) it's difficult to choose here,  but you better do it. So we keep the community alive. Check https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14593/is-it-ok-to-not-accept-an-answer-out-of-many-equally-good-ones then please accept one.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This is how you install libusb:

```
sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev
```

Note that if you are using libusb in a C/C++ program you should include it the following way:

```
#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>
```

and not like this:

```
#include <libusb.h>
```

This is a common mistake that I was making. Finally you compile like this:

```
g++ source.cpp `pkg-config --libs --cflags libusb-1.0`
```

Comment: Not sure that you need to specify the version. `sudo apt-get install libusb-dev` worked fine for me.

Comment: @CharlieJoynt In that case, how did you include libusb in your code and how did you compile it?

Comment: I came across this when trying to `./configure` the libmtp library from Sourceforge. It was failing with an error saying the `libusb` library was missing. I resolved it with the command in my comment above. 'fraid it has been a long while since I wrote any C/C++ code myself. Since the OP only mentioned installing the package, I thought it might be useful to share my experience.

Comment: I had a face-in-palm moment when I realized I had to omit "lib" from "libusb-1.0" in order to get ld to find the library.  Just like -lz links libz.so, "-lusb-1.0" is the correct string.

Comment: @CharlieJoynt You should specify the version, or at least be aware if your program needs a particular version, because on some platforms libusb-dev is not the same as libusb-1.0-0-dev (e.g. Raspberry Pi).

Comment: You will sometimes also require `libudev-dev`

Answer (score 6):

Since you are new to linux I suggest running the below command from terminal to install libusb directly from the repository:

`>sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev`

If you wish to continue with the archive you have downloaded, refer to the instructions in the below link:

http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/libusb.html