# How to update libusb? [Ubuntu 14.04]

Tags: apt, upgrade, usb, package-management, updates

I recently tried installing libusb(and failing) using the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev
```

as mentioned on the [askUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/629619/how-to-install-libusb). But I got errors saying following packages couldn't be installed: libusb-1.0-0-dev: libusb-1.0-0-dev (2:1.0.21-1) will be installed
*(note- I don't remember the exact error since I moved on and installed it using cmake by downloading the .tar file)*

So I changed the command accordingly but still in vain. Due to the persistent error I installed the package from the [Ubuntu repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libusb-1.0-0-dev). Details of the package I downloaded:

```
amd64   53.4 kB 281.0 kB    [list of files]
```

Now I am trying to use Mircosoft Kinect V2 for SLAM through libfreenect2 on Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS Indigo and getting an error:

```
[Error] [Freenect2Impl] Your libusb does not support large iso buffer!
no device connected!
```

After Googling and stackoverflowing I figured out that this error is due to an [older version of libusb](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2/issues/410). So I checked the version using the following command from another [askUbuntu Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/790998/how-can-i-check-the-version-of-libusb-1-0-running-on-ubuntu-14-04) :

`dpkg -l libusb-1.0*`

The output I received detailed that the version number is 1.0.17 however the latest is available online is [1.0.21](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb/)

```
||/ Name                          Version             Architecture        Description
+++-=============================-===================-===================-===============================================================
ii  libusb-1.0-0:amd64            2:1.0.17-1ubuntu2   amd64               userspace USB programming library
ii  libusb-1.0-0-dev:amd64        2:1.0.17-1ubuntu2   amd64               userspace USB programming library development files
ii  libusb-1.0-doc                2:1.0.17-1ubuntu2   all
```

It makes perfect sense because I downloaded the 1.0.17 version. Now **how can I update libusb 1.0.17 to 1.0.20.**

I have already tried the following commands as mentioned on [askUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44122/how-to-upgrade-a-single-package-using-apt-get):

```
sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install libusb-1.0-0-dev
sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev
```

but not of much use. The version of libusb is still 1.0.17. Kindly suggest another method to update it to 1.0.20. In case you recommend deleting the existing version and reinstalling the new version 1.0.20 then kindly outline the steps to delete the libusb 1.0.17 (keep in mind that I installed it using make).

**[EDIT - Ubuntu 14.04]**
and I cannot upgrade to 16.04 since the packages that I need to work with are compatible with 14.04 only

Comment: Upgrade to 16.04.

Comment: By the way, installing libusb from source may have broken your system, in which case the above becomes "wipe your system and install a fresh 16.04."

Comment: What!! that will be alot of WORK then. How can I verify if my system is broken?

Comment: For example if it still doesn't work after upgrading to 16.04, it could mean that the version you installed from source is interfering with the one provided by the system.

Comment: this link might be helpful in installing [1.0.20](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2/issues/390) .